# Algorithm - Range Query

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given an array *A* of *n* elements, we have to answer *m* queries of type *i,j,X*. For each query we have to output the numbers in range *i,j* that are greater than *X*.

E.g.:

If the array is:

> 3 4 1 7

and the query was *1 4 3* i.e. we have to output numbers greater than 3 in the range 1 to 4.

Output:
2

Since three numbers are greater than 3 (4, 7)

Constraints:

```
1 < n < 10^5
1 < A[i] < 10^9
```

My Approach:

I tried to approach it using segments tree of segments of *sqrt(n)*. It gives the time complexity of *O(sqrt(n))*.

Is there any other method to solve it in a smaller complexity?

Comment: How can i answer Queries of type 'C' in a time less than |P-Q| . what data structure should i use so i can answer these queries very fast.

Comment: Is it part of your homework?

Comment: No. I just want to solve it. I looks like a question of implementing Segment tree. But i have idea of how to solve this question..

Comment: I have changed the question. I think i should be now more clear.

Comment: Edited my answer to describe the O(log^2 n) algorithm.

Comment: _"i.e. we have to output numbers greater than 3 in the range 1 to 4.
Output: 2"_ - that doesn't make sense. 2 is less than 3. You also didn't specify if the range is inclusive. And if the resulting numbers need to be (not) present in the array.

Answer (score 4):

The data structure that you're looking for is a 2D [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree). The following approach, with O(sqrt(n) log n) operation time, may be easier to implement however. (I'll leave the improvement to O(sqrt(n log n)) as an exercise.)

Divide the cows into sqrt(n) contiguous blocks of sqrt(n) cows. For each block, store the signs normally and additionally in sorted order. When an M query is processed, make the necessary change and resort (time O(sqrt(n) log n)). When a C query is processed, use brute force in the unsorted arrays for the partially overlapped blocks (time O(sqrt(n))) and binary search in the sorted arrays for the wholly contained blocks (time O(sqrt(n) log n)).

Here's the O(log^2 n) query time version. Keep a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) of sorted multisets, where each sorted multiset containing the signs for the cows in the segment. When an M query is processed, delete the cow's old sign from all of the multisets for segments containing that cow. Reinsert the cow's new sign in a similar fashion. When a C query is processed, partition the query interval into O(log n) segments and examine the number of elements in each sorted multiset that are in range. The best way to support this latter operation probably is a binary search tree where each node stores the number of nodes in its left child's subtree. The reason that I didn't suggest this first is that (i) it requires a lot more implementation effort (ii) for n = 100000, the difference in running time functions is sqrt(n)/log(n)**(3/2) ~ 8, which more than likely will be swallowed up by the relative cache-friendliness of the two approaches and the additional complexity of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
```

```
/*
```

This file is both C and Markdown.

The data structure you are looking for needs to answer "three-sided
range queries". They are called *three-sided* because you can picture
your array as representing n points in a two-dimensional set, where
the x coordinate is the array index and the y coordinate is the value
at that index; your query then amounts to "print all of the y
coordinates of points (x,y) where i <= x <= j and y > X". This is
three inequalities on the values printed.

One very simple data structure that can support three-sized range
queries is a priority search tree (PST).

```
*/

typedef struct NODE {
  int y_max;
  struct NODE *left, *right;
} Node;

/*
```

For your usage, you can use a very simple priority search tree. The
tree will have 2*n - 1 nodes. Leaf nodes are associated with a single
location in the array. Non-leaf nodes are associated with a contiguous
region of the array. The association is as follows:

- The root is associated with the whole array: positions [0, n)
- The left child of a node with range [a,b) is associated with
  positions [a, floor((a + b)/2))
- The right child of a node with range [a,b) is associated with
  positions [floor((a+b)/2), b)

If a region is empty, no node is stored for it.

The association is implicit and not stored anywhere; it can be
inferred from n and the shape of the tree.

Each node additionally stores the maximum value among all of the
values stores in its associated region.

For instance, if your array is {60, 70, 80, 90, 100}, then the tree
nodes and their associated regions and values are:

```
                       [0,5):100
                      /         \
              [0,2):70           [2,5):100
             /       \          /         \
     [0,1):60   [1,2):70    [2,3):80     [3,5):100
                                        /         \
                                    [3,4):90   [4,5):100
```

Constructing a PST takes linear time using recursion:

```
*/

int Max(int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }

Node * Construct(int n, int ys[]) {
  if (!n) return NULL;
  Node *result = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (1 == n) {
    result->y_max = ys[n];
    result->left = result->right = NULL;
  } else {
    // To find y_max, we first recurse:
    result->left = Construct(n / 2, ys);
    result->right = Construct(n - n / 2, ys + n / 2);
    // The the y_max is the max of the child y_max values:
    result->y_max = Max(result->left->y_max, result->right->y_max);
  }
  return result;
}

/*
```

To query a PST, you need to find all leaves of the tree that are in
the given `[i, j]` region with `y_max > X`. This can also be done
recursively:

```
*/

void Query(int a, int b, Node *pst, int i, int j, int X) {
  if (!pst || a > j || b < i || pst->y_max <= X) return;
  if (b - a == 1) printf("%d ", pst->y_max);
  Query(a, (a + b) / 2, pst->left, i, j, X);
  Query((a + b) / 2, b, pst->right, i, j, X);
}

/*
```

A careful accounting shows that the time complexity is O(log n + k),
where k is the number of nodes reported. Note that the lower bound on
***any*** data structure supporting these queries is Ω(k), since
it takes that much time just to print the results.

You can find many careful accountings by just Googling "priority
search tree".

The data structure above is sub-optimal in a number of ways, but it is
simple to explain this way. It can be organized to be stored in an
array of size n/2 + O(1), rather than Θ(n) tree nodes as above.

---

Updates can be performed in O(log n) time by traversing down the tree
recursively and rebuilding `y_max` on the way back up:

```
*/

void Update(int i, int v, int a, int b, Node *pst) {
  if (a + 1 == b) {
    pst->y_max = v;
    return;
  }
  // Recurse down one subtree:
  int mid = (a + b) / 2;
  if (i < mid) {
    Update(i, v, a, mid, pst->left);
  } else {
    Update(i, v, mid, b, pst->right);
  }
  pst->y_max = Max(pst->left->y_max, pst->right->y_max);
}
```